# Fixing navbar collapse positioning and color on width adjustment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Code on here in my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zo8md2rq/

[image]

I have a collapsible navbar with my code shown in my fiddle.

I tried to have the css change on my nav on width adjustment, turning my color from orange to white and placing my collapsible to the right, but my CSS now does neither

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-color {
    color: white !important;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

I would like to accomplish:

- Have the css change as soon as the navbar collapses too
- Not use "min-width" if possible

Comment: Did you want to change color (font) or background-color? And is `min-width` supposed to be `max-width` since it is for responsive design?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a typo in your CSS, at line 25 it should be `rgba`, not `rgb`.

Then, if I understand your request correctly, all you have to do is add `float-sm-right` class to your `navbar-toggler` button, like this:

`<button class="navbar-toggler float-sm-right" ...`